# Android SQL (SQLite) not Working

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I would like to add feature where
1. when a save button in the Main Activity is clicked it groups variables (type String, String, int, int, boolean) to an item and inserts it to a database and

2. in the list screen all inserted items would appear in list view.`enter code here`

MainActivity.java

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
.
.
.

// db
    final DatabaseActivity manager = new DatabaseActivity(this);
.
.
.

    bt_check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {   
.
.
.
    manager.insertData(edittext.getText().toString(),"hello",font_color,true);
.
.
.
        }
    }); }
```

DatabaseAcitivity.java

```
    public class DatabaseActivity {
    .
    .
    .
    public void insertData(String text, String bg, int font, boolean locked) {
    String sql = "insert into " + tableName +
            "(text, bg, font, locked) values(" +
            "'"+ text + "', " +
            "'"+ bg + "', " +
            "'"+ font + "', " +
            "'"+ locked + "')";
    db.execSQL(sql);
}
.
.   
.

    }
```

MemoListItem.java

```
    public class MemoListItem {


private int mid;
private String mbg;
private String mtext;
private int mfont;
private boolean mlocked;


MemoListItem(int id,String bg,String text,int font,boolean locked)
{
    mid = id;
    mbg = bg;
    mtext = text;
    mfont = font;
    mlocked = locked;
}
.
.   
.
    }
```

MemoListAdapter.java

```
    .
    .
    .
    public class MemoListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {

private MemoListItem mUser
private Context mContext;
.
.
.

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = convertView;

    if (v == null) {

        v = ((LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
                .inflate(R.layout.layout_listview,null);


        cb_listlock = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.cb_listlock);
        noti_textview = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.noti_textview);
        noti_bg = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.Noti_bg);
        bt_edit = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.bt_edit);
    }


    mUser = getItem(position);


    if (mUser != null) {

        if (mUser.getbg() != null) {
        noti_bg.setImageBitmap(mUser.getbg());
       }
        noti_textview.setText(mUser.getText());
        cb_listlock.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    return v;
}

.
.
.
    }
```

ListActivity.java

```
    public class ListActivity extends Activity {
.
.
.

SQLiteDatabase database;
com.xxx.xxx.MemoListAdapter MemoListAdapter;
.
.
.

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
.
.
.
    MemoListAdapter = new MemoListAdapter(this);
    mMemolistview.setAdapter(MemoListAdapter);
    mMemolistview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
.
.
.

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
            viewMemo(position);
        }
    });
.
.
.
}

    protected void onStart() {
    database = openOrCreateDatabase(dbName, MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE, null);
    loadmemo();
    super.onStart();
}

private void loadmemo(){

String sql = "select * from " + "memo" + ";";
Cursor results = database.rawQuery(sql, null);
results.moveToFirst();


while (!results.isAfterLast()) {

    Integer memoid = results.getInt(0);
    String text = results.getString(1);
    String bg =  results.getString(2);
    boolean locked = (results.getInt(4)!=0);
    int font = results.getInt(3);


    MemoListAdapter.addItem(new MemoListItem(memoid,text,bg,font,locked));
    results.moveToNext();
}

results.close();

    }


    }
```

Currently, the item is inserted correctly to the database but on the ListView the object appears without content. Would you please provide some insight to the source of the problem?

Comment: This is sqlite, not android sql ;)

Comment: Use cursor loader,whenever data will insert in to db, cursor loader will invoke automattically and set adapter

Comment: What does `not Working` mean? please post your logcat.

Comment: There are no problems or errors on logcat tho thanks

Comment: i will try thank you